Calling method missing in async stack trace
I have the following code in a WPF .NET 8 application.
When the exception is hit, the only callstack is:
WpfApp119.ViewModel.Compute() Line 23   C#
WpfApp119.ViewModel.LoadData.AnonymousMethod__0_0() Line 18 C#
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(System.Threading.Thread threadPoolThread, System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)  Unknown
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot, System.Threading.Thread threadPoolThread)   Unknown
System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() Unknown
System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()    Unknown

So you don't know whether it was called from MainWindow.Button_Click1 or MainWindow.Button_Click2.
So if this code was in a real app, or in a test, how would you diagnose where the call originated from?
public class ViewModel
{
    public async Task LoadData()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Compute());
    }

    private void Compute()
    {
        throw new Exception("");
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ViewModel _viewModel = new();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await _viewModel.LoadData();
    }

    private async void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await _viewModel.LoadData();
    }
}


The event should be present in the stack: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kTIBFY

@TheodorZoulias .NET 8

@shingo haven't you changed the code though? if I run this code in a normal WPF app, I get the stack I posted above.

How do you catch this stack in a normal WPF app?

Just a simple try/catch inside of Compute() and then log exception (with its stack)

That's the problem, you should not do that. You can catch the exception within the UnhandledException event.

That would give the same issue with the partial callstack. But I also would not want to have it be unhandled, when I can catch it and gracefully handle the exception.

You can't find out from the given code snippet.  You are probably asking this question because you haven't yet thought about the concurrency issues in this code.  Nothing stops the user from clicking either button again, running LoadData() concurrently and out of sync on multiple threads.  This rarely comes to a good end, you merely hope the user learns not to do this.  Do something about that problem, like disabling a button while the async code is executing, and you'll have enough state to know how it all happened.  And avoid concurrency bugs.

@HansPassant absolutely. In the real code I would be using an IAsyncCommand which would disable the button. But I was trying to keep the example to the point.

What you show looks perfectly reasonable. This is because .NET asynchronous model is based on multiple threads. If you perform the test as you described and have an unhandled exception, you really cannot directly see what button initiated the problematic piece of code simply because the button handling code never calls it directly. Your await call, strictly speaking, is not a call, the real underlying call was performed by some instance of System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.
The call stack (and, by the way, the exception stack created by all of your try points as they are passed during runtime) belongs to one single thread, and is one of the most important parts of the thread identity — if two threads are different, they are executed on two different call stacks. And the thread showing your stack trace is not you UI thread.
Forget about async for a second, but create a thread in your code during runtime and start it using System.Threading.Thread.Start. Isn't it obvious that the code running by this newly created thread contains no information on how it was started? There is nothing on its call stack beyond the thread start method passed to the Thread constructor. The same thing goes for your buttons.
And if the information on the button that originated your problematic piece of code is not known to some thread, is it even important? Anyway, if, for debugging purposes, you need to find out which button originated the asynchronous call, you can always run the debugging session where you click only one button and never click another one. :-)
